# Any suggestions for how to format an RFC822 email as JSON?

Tags: json, email, rfc822

I am wanting to insert RFC822 emails into a JSON database.

I'm wanting to envisage a "good" way to structure the email as JSON (excluding attachments).

Does anyone know of an example of a "good" JSON layout for an email, alternatively can anyone suggest one?

thanks

UPDATE: I'm actually looking to see the JSON output rather than the code to do the conversion.

Comment: Why JSON?  Why not just Base-64 encode the whole thing, including attachments?  Is the idea that you want the e-mail content to be searchable once it has been inserted in the database?

Comment: Yes, it's going into a JSON database and I want to be able to access fields.

Answer (score 0):

Not done it specifically, but the [Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) includes a method for serializing methods to YAML, and also for parsing messages from YAML. It does this by constructing a `Hash` object and then serializing that object to JSON. That also means it should be easy to convert to JSON.

This would prolly look (ish) like this…

```
require 'json'

module Mail
  class Message
    def to_json(opts = {})
      hash = {}
      hash['headers'] = {}
      header.fields.each do |field|
        hash['headers'][field.name] = field.value
      end
      hash['delivery_handler'] = delivery_handler.to_s if delivery_handler
      hash['transport_encoding'] = transport_encoding.to_s
      special_variables = [:@header, :@delivery_handler, :@transport_encoding]
      (instance_variables.map(&:to_sym) - special_variables).each do |var|
        hash[var.to_s] = instance_variable_get(var)
      end
      hash.to_json(opts)
    end        
  end
end
```

From the [`Message#to_yaml`](https://github.com/mikel/mail) method of mikel's Mail gem.

You could take a similar approach in any language. If you're using Ruby though, this would fit great with your existing tooling (the Mail gem).

Comment: Thanks for your response although I'm actually looking to see the JSON output rather than the code to do the conversion

Answer (score 0):

You probably want some variant of something that lists the headers and body parts.

```
 {
       headers: [
          { name: value },
          { name2: value}
       ],
       body: [
           { 
               mime: type,
               content: stuff
           },
           {
           },
           .
           .
           .
           {
           }
       ]
    }
```